# pre-commit mypy with additional_dependencies from custom Pypi index

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

In my `.pre-commit-config.yaml`, I have the following config for `mypy`:

```
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v0.971
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        args: [--strict]
        additional_dependencies:
          [
            apache-airflow==2.3.3,
            apache-airflow-providers-apache-hive==4.0.0,
            apache-airflow-providers-apache-livy==3.1.0,
            types-protobuf==3.20.4,
          ]
```

This works ok if all these dependencies come from the public pypi index. What should I do if I have a package comes from a custom pypi index? How can I update my config in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you need custom packages you'll utilize the same `--index-url` argument you'd send to `pip` in `additional_dependencies`:

```yaml
        additional_dependencies:
          [
            '--index-url=https://example.com/simple',
            apache-airflow==2.3.3,
            apache-airflow-providers-apache-hive==4.0.0,
            apache-airflow-providers-apache-livy==3.1.0,
            types-protobuf==3.20.4,
          ]
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Thanks Anthony! What if some packages come from Pypi while others come from my private pypi index? At the moment, my private pypi doesn't contain all public indexes.

Comment: it's not different than pip, so `--extra-index-url=...` -- though **note that extra-index-url is a security problem as someone could namesnipe your internal packages** so you probably don't want to do that